# Set Video Ringtone For Incoming Calls on Android

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-video-player, android-videoview

i have designed a call screen by using the concept of broadcast receiver.my requirement is to implement a video call screen,so that when some one calls to my device at that time a video file will be played in the call screen and previous normal ringtone will be stopped.